# Issue occured while packaging the SharePoint 2007 solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have added the web service reference in to SharePoint solution,When I package the solution I got below error

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:1378

Could you please advice why the error occurred?

As I am struggling more for this issue.

Comment: are you packaging from Visual Studio or you trying to deploy the solution?

Answer (score 0):

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" means the server could be reached and responded within the timeout, but the **specified port wasn't open**.

This can have several reasons

**e.g.** a local firewall blocking the connection.

Can you check the server is listening on the right IP/port?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response,

Yes, I am packaging from visual studio.

Can you please advice how can I Enable the firewall connection for particular Port

Yes, Server pinging as excepted.

And I have pinged this IP address through CMD prompt "result  showing as  0% loss"   - ping 127:0.0.1

When I run this Cmd (netstat -anb) in CMD prompt I have not seen this(1378) port along with IP address (127.0.0.1:1378)